# Center channel audio on windows 10 is muffled

Tags: windows-10, audio

On my desktop, I use the multichannel outputs of my motherboard (MSI z170a gaming m5) to output 7.1 audio to my receiver, which in turn powers my 7.1 system. I also have it connected via optical cable. I noticed that my center channel audio (whether in games, or movies/tv shows) is muffled when using the multichannel output. This problem does not occur when using the digital output, but I prefer to use analog connections as games that support positional audio (basically everything) can't do positional audio over the optical cable -- only the multichannel surround. The center channel is the only channel I have this issue with, but it is significant. Especially when watching movies, there is a drastic change in clarity between dialogue coming from the center versus playing it in stereo mode and having it come from the R/L fronts.

To troubleshoot, I have tried:

1. Using a different(identical model) speaker for the center, no luck
2. Swapping cables from the PC to the receiver
3. changing any and all Realtek audio manager settings I could find

I cant figure out why this is happening. I am on Windows 10 1903, and my receiver is the Onkyo HT-R340. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Temporarily swap the centre output to another location, Left, for instance. See if the muffled sound moves to the left or stays with the centre speaker. Also test with a dedicated multichannel sound test file to eliminate decoding errors.

Comment: I have tried swapping -- It is persistent with the center channel audio (not the speaker, but the speaker that the receiver outputs center channel audio to). I have tried with multichannel audio as well as positional audio and both have the same issue. Even using the realtek audio managers speaker test (click on a speaker, makes a chime to make sure its working) sounds muffled for the center channel, but fine for the other 6 speakers.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just to add on, i don't think that it would be a decoding error. This only occurs when using the 3.5mm outputs from my PC to connect to my receivers RCA inputs. Using the optical cable results in crisp audio from the center channel. I use the analog outputs so that way I can play games and use positional audio -- Receiver only decodes Dolby Digital and DTS, which very few, if any at all, games encode their audio in.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just to make sure it wasn't the center channel RCA input on my receiver that was defective, I inputted center channel audio to a different input and re wired the speakers accordingly, with the same issue.  I have localized the issue to be within my computer.

Comment: I actually meant swap the channels in software before they leave the decoder, as you'd already eliminated cable & speaker. But as the Realtek test agrees, then it is something between decoder & output.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just tried retasking the connectors to use a different output for center channel. So definitely between decoder and output. specifically the Realtek HD Audio decoder and output. I am curious to try using another audio driver and see if the problem persists